# Add labels inside of ScrollView Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

I want to display labels and buttons inside a Scrollview. 
Can anybody tell me how this is done?

```
@IBOutlet weak var PeopleView: UIScrollView!

 var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
     button.frame = CGRectMake("INSIDE SCROLL.VIEW", "INSIDE SCROLL.VIEW", 183, 21)
     button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
     button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
     button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
     self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line of code

```
self.PeopleView.addSubview(button)
```

instead of

```
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

and make sure you are passing a `CGFloat` value while giving buttons or labels frame